# Swift : How to perform back action when using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode8, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using **SWRevealViewController** for SideMenu bar option on HomeVC of my app.

When user taps on any button present in HomeVC it navigates to another screen (*PushViewController*). In this new view controller I've shown custom back button.

Now, when user taps on this back button the *view should get poped to HomeVC.* Below is code that I've used:

**HomeViewController :**

```
@IBAction func recharge_Mobile(_ sender: UIButton) {

   let objRechargeMobileViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idRechargeMobileViewController") as! RechargeMobileViewController
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objRechargeMobileViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

**RechargeViewController :**

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:"back.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(btnBack_Clicked()))

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
  . . .   
  }

     @IBAction func btnBack_Clicked() {
           /* for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
                if controller.isKind(of: ViewController()) {
                    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller as! ViewController, animated: true)
                    break
                }
            } */

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This should have worked...The only way we can help is seeing the project.

Comment: Did you add any Navigation controller in your storyboard?

Comment: @HrishikeshMenon : Yes, I've added it

Comment: " When user taps on any button present in HomeVC it navigates to another screen (PushViewController). In this new view controller I've shown custom back button. "
is the button inside your HomeVC or in the sidemenuVC